# how to get sentence values from wordpress shortcode parameter?

Tags: php, shortcode

I've set up a shortcode that gets sentence value from parameter, but it only returns the first word of the sentence. I've assumed that the shortcode recognizes values after whitespaces, but when I use double quotes, it breaks the shortcode. is there any workaround on this? thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
function summary_items( $atts , $content = null) {

    $defaults = shortcode_atts( array(
        'item' => '------',
    ), $atts );

    $output = '<li>'. esc_attr($defaults['item']) .'</li>';
    return $output;

}

add_shortcode( 'summary_items', 'summary_items' );
```

I use it like this:

```
[summary_items item=this is a test] //this outputs "this" only.
[summary_items item="this is a test"] // breaks the shortcode
```

Comment: Double quotes shouldn't break anything. In fact they're necessary for what you want to do. Does it break when you use `this is a test` or are you using something else? Also, are you making sure to use regular double quotes `"` and not fancy quotes `”`?

Comment: `esc_attr()` encodes `<, >, &, ” and ‘` if they are present in the string. Try using `esc_html()` instead.

Comment: What "It breaks the shortcode means" ?
I've tested it on a test website https://i.imgur.com/W5uN12F.png